# How do I conditionally change axis scale in a crystal reports chart?

Tags: crystal-reports, charts, crystal-reports-xi

Is there a way (or workaround) to conditionally set the max and min values (and perhars even tick intervals) of an axis in a crystal reports chart?

I want to be able to have the same scale on two different line charts where one is peaking about 75' and the other around 110', which makes auto values choose different scales. Setting the values manually means I have to change the values if the numbers undergo larger change at some time, and makes the report less reusable on other differently sized business units.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issues with charts in Crystal Reports.  The best I've been able to do is play with the "Number of divisions" option on the Axes tab in Chart Expert.  Also, in the "Data Values" section, the Auto Scale checkbox is not checked by default in my version.  In Xcelsius (Crystal Dashboards) you can easily set the axis range by cell reference but Crystal Reports doesn't appear to give us that option.